# how to remove this char "�" from string output

Tags: php, character-encoding

the only way to see it when output a substring

Comment: Please provide mind-boggling amounts of additional detail.  What did it come from? What is it supposed to be? What encoding is your page?

Comment: That character it's used in many cases to represent a non-printable character, it may be caused by a wrong encoding, garbage characters, wrong length, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a substring function that doesn't assume 1 byte = 1 character. Unicode has been around long enough that everything should be prepared for it.

[mb_substr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php)

Comment: Really?  I though Unicode was a modern standard.  Has it been replaced by MultiCode?

Comment: Unicode is a modern standard, it has just been around long enough (since 1987!) that everybody should be using it (and not using string functions that can't handle it). Multibyte just means that some characters are made up of more than a single byte (because there are more characters in Unicode then there are combinations of bits in a byte).

Comment: That was my funny little way of saying that your answer suggests that Unicode is too old.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you're not providing any relative information, the answer most probably is : use the correct character encoding when you display the text (either use iconv or set the relevant headers so your browser knows what to expect) and/or use multibyte functions when replacing fragments.